# Wrong locale chosen for custom validation

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, validation, internationalization

I have a form which I need to validate. So I am using formtastic together with client_side_validations:

```
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'client_side_validations-formtastic'
```

The following validation is set up for the terms and conditions, which a user must accept:

```
validates :accepts_terms, :acceptance => {
    message: I18n.t('order_form.validation.terms_not_accepted')
}
```

The validation as such works fine but for some reason the wrong locale is chosen so I get the following message:

```
translation missing: de.order_form.validation.terms_not_accepted
```

On the screenshot you can see that for the other fields the correct translation is chosen so it says `Can't be blank` rather than the German translations.

So I have two questions:

1. Why is the locale `de` rather than `en` like for the rest of the form
2. Even if `de` is selected, why is the translated value for the key `de.order_form.validation.terms_not_accepted` not used, which is present in `de.yml`.

#### de.yml

```
de:
  order_form:
    validation:
      terms_not_accepted: "muss akzeptiert werden"
```

#### Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you post more code. There my be a typo somewhere or something, the more eyes the better.

Comment: @Jack I guess the relevant code bits should be here. Also the rest of the form is clearly English, while the translation says `de.order_form...` so this won't be based on a typo. Also the missing tranlsation and the present translation for `terms_not_accepted` match. So Rails does not have a reason to complain.

Comment: It looks like this might be an error of the validations plugin that I am using so I have opened an issue at https://github.com/dockyard/client_side_validations-formtastic/issues/13

Comment: My bad, I thought you were saying it was not referencing the english translation where it should, but I don't see where it's defined, which is why I asked for more. –– Good luck :D